# Sonicwall firewalls and redundancy of route based vpns

Tags: vpn, route, redundancy, sonicwall

I am attempting to configure a route based vpn on a Sonicwall TZ device.

The datacenter has two public IPs on different subnets (A and B).  The remote office has 1 public ip (C).

When I configure two tunnels from the datacenter firewall to the remote office (A to C as well as B to C), one of them always fails, most likely due to the same terminating IP address (C) at the remote site.

Sonicwall documentation states that this should be feasible but their tech support is unable to figure out how to get it to work.

Does anyone have experience configuring redundancy using sonicwall route based vpns?

Answer (score 1):

We have this same problem between an NSA3500 and TZ215. Let me know if you make any headway. I have logged a case with Sonicwall Tech support (useless) and they mention it is not possible to have multiple SA's for the same remote gateway even if the local endpoints are different.